# Python - can't figure out how to multiply 2 panels (3D arrays) without looping

Tags: python, pandas, multidimensional-array

I have a panel like this:

```
values = ['count1','count2','price1','price2']
fruit = ['apple','orange']
days = ['d1','d2']

dictx = {}

list_count = []
list_price = []

for v in values:
    if 'count' in v:
        dictx[v] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(len(days), len(fruit))), columns=fruit)
        list_count.append(v)
    else:
        dictx[v] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(days), len(fruit)), columns=fruit)
        list_price.append(v)
pan = pd.Panel.from_dict(dictx)
```

Without looping (pretend I had "count" and "price" items 1-100000), I am trying to achieve this:

```
    (pan.ix['count1',:,:] * pan.ix['price1',:,:]) 
  + (pan.ix['count2',:,:] * pan.ix['price2',:,:]) 
  + (pan.ix['countn',:,:] * pan.ix['pricen',:,:])
```

I created `list_count` and `list_price` as I thought they could be used like this:  `pan.ix[list_count,:,:]` & `pan.ix[list_price,:,:]`

So I have one more dimension than I know how to deal with at the moment. I hope there is some wonderful 3D array or panel function that can swing this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you might be looking for this:

```
sum(pan.ix[list_count].values * pan.ix[list_price].values)
```

The `.values` attribute is a numpy array which then lets you do your elementwise multiplication, addition, etc.

**Example**

```
>>> pan.ix[list_count].values
array([[[8, 9],
        [2, 0]],

       [[5, 1],
        [8, 3]]])

>>> pan.ix[list_price].values
array([[[ 0.57644595,  0.52264882],
        [ 0.82041129,  0.16165434]],

       [[ 0.08450438,  0.58036628],
        [ 0.90809822,  0.77834048]]])

>>> pan.ix[list_count].values * pan.ix[list_price].values
array([[[ 4.6115676 ,  4.7038394 ],
        [ 1.64082259,  0.        ]],

       [[ 0.42252192,  0.58036628],
        [ 7.26478578,  2.33502144]]])

>>> sum(pan.ix[list_count].values * pan.ix[list_price].values)
array([[ 5.03408952,  5.28420568],
       [ 8.90560837,  2.33502144]])
```

Comment: good answer bunji. thanks. trying to make it work - generating a single number output for some reason.

Comment: hey bunji. i think this is giving me the 2d output i was looking for... pd.DataFrame((pan.ix[list_count].values * pan.ix[list_price].values).sum(axis=0))